# Zimbra: Modifying to Send Email on Email Recieved

Tags: email, cron, zimbra

I need Zimbra to detect an incoming email and run some code. I'm new to Zimbra and am still learning how it all fits together, but from what I can tell there are a few ways to go about this.

1. Does Zimbra already run a script when an email is received? If so I could just add a few lines.
2. Does Zimbra log incoming email? If so I could check that every so often and see what new emails have come in.
3. Could create a scheduled job to query the database for new emails since last check.

Any ideas on where to go with this?

--
**Some boring specifics:**
The people in the office don't check their work emails enough and are missing important stuff. My job is to send a notification email to their personal email address when they get mew mail

Comment: So the solution to not reading emails is to... send more email? Perhaps drowning people need more water poured on their heads, or people on fire are obviously short a gallon of gas.

Comment: That's the problem, they rarely get emails but when they do they're too important to miss. Because there are so few emails people get lazy, myself included.

Comment: Consider an out-of-band notifier, like a desktop popup instead. If people don't check their emails, there's no point in sending an email to tell them they've got an email - they won't be checking their email to read the notification.

Comment: Just to be clear I'm talking about sending a notification to their personal email (ex: gmail), when they receive an email at their work address (@company). The work email is only used for sending sensitive documents, which is why it's used rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zimbra can auto-forward to any address, but it can't run scripts on receipt without a lot of work.  It's designed to scale to large installations, so (for one thing) it tries not to do anything per-recipient for a large distribution list.  So e.g. there's no procmail and no real way to hook it up.